# Use array values to create a SimpleXML value string

Tags: php, simplexml

I wonder if anyone of you could help me with an issue i'm having. I've searched around but can't seem to locate the solution so thought i would ask here :)

Basically i have an array that contains the field_id i want to use and the the value is another array containing the element names that are required to be strung together to access a SimpleXML node that contains the value i wish to retrieve.

E.G.

```
    array (
        'route_id' => array('Services', 'Service', 'ServiceCode'),
        'agency_id' => array('Services', 'Service', 'RegisteredOperatorRef'),
        'route_short_name' => array('Services', 'Service', 'LineName'),
        'route_long_name' => '',
        'route_desc' => array('Services', 'Service', 'Description'),
        'route_type' => array('Services', 'Service', 'Mode'),
        'route_url' => '',
        'route_color' => '',
        'route_text_color' => '',
    );
```

As you can see the id 'route_id' is contained under

```
$xmlobject->Services->Service->ServiceCode
```

and so on and so forth.

Now when i am processing that particular area i am trying to implode the fields using

```
implode('->', $fields)
```

This approach basically doesn't seem to be working and returns empty but i can access the value is i physically type out the exact same path.

I was wondering if there is any solution to this or will i have to find an alternate way of writing this?

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: `->` is an operator, so you can't "implode" to build an "operator chain"...although `eval` would accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->` is an operator, so if you *REALLY* want to build it into string and ask PHP to parse it, you'll need to try [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

But you don't have to, as you can chain-go to your destination with some kind of loop:

```
function findText($entry,array $api,SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    if(!empty($api[$entry]))
    {
        $cache=$xml;
        foreach($api[$entry] as $node)
        {
            $cache=$cache->{$node};
        }
        return (String)$cache;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/WrZNF) with the following data:

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Services>
        <Service>
            <ServiceCode>Route ID</ServiceCode>
            <RegisteredOperatorRef>Agency ID</RegisteredOperatorRef>
            <LineName>Route Short Name</LineName>
            <Description>Route Description</Description>
            <Mode>Route Type</Mode>
        </Service>
    </Services>
</root>
```

```php
$xml=simplexml_load_string(/* XML */);
$api=array (
    'route_id' => array('Services', 'Service', 'ServiceCode'),
    'agency_id' => array('Services', 'Service', 'RegisteredOperatorRef'),
    'route_short_name' => array('Services', 'Service', 'LineName'),
    'route_desc' => array('Services', 'Service', 'Description'),
    'route_type' => array('Services', 'Service', 'Mode')
);
echo findText("route_id",$api,$xml);
```

Echos `Route ID` from PHP 5.1 and up (although you may want to add some error handling codes in the loop in case of incorrect path or alike).

Comment: Thanks Passerby i ended up using this approach in the end. Looping through each array iteration to the end point. :)